# Beautify vscode plugin, how to remove ; from end of line?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, format, js-beautify

I am using Beautify vscode plugin with a file: `.jsbeautifyrc`

But every time I saved my file, Beautify adds a ; at the end of line.

Before save:

```
this.user.name = 'Lucas Andrade'
```

After save:

```
this.user.name = 'Lucas Andrade';
```

But I don't want the ; at the end of line.

There is any configuration to tell Beautify to put nothing at the end of file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using prettier:
https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode#prettiersemi-default-true

Alternatively you need eslint rules.

VSCode Beautify plugin doesn't seem have a setting for removing semicolons.

EDIT:
For the ones interested on how to actually configure prettier or eslint:

Prettier: `"semi": false`

ESLint: `semi: "error"` (Note: You might want to run `eslint --fix` after setting that rule)

Comment: What are the settings to make it Add semi-colons?

Comment: Ive seen this a bit late, ill update my answer, in case you or others are still looking for it.